# How to test cli (global link) with yarn?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, yarnpkg

I am trying to test a cli ([feathers-cli](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-cli)) that I am working on. I have cloned it's primary dependancy (feathers-generator) and made my modifications, this is what I have done.

1. Gone into feathers-generator (master branch) and run `yarn link`
2. Gone into feathers-cli (3.0 branch) and run `yarn link "feathers-generator"`
3. Run `yarn link`
4. created a new directory, removed my existing version of feathers-cli
5. Run `yarn link "feathers-cli"` then run `yarn global add "feathers-cli"`

`feathers` however, at this point it is using the regular version it has pulled from npm. I have looked through the yarn docs and can't seem to find anything about globally linking packages. How do I approach this?

Comment: I generally just stick to an `npm install -g .`, when testing global installs locally. Although this may not entirely solve your need to do it with `yarn`

Comment: As per [Yarn link doesn't link binaries globally](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/891), this isn't possible, at least not with yarn v1.

Answer (score 2):

With yarn v1.19 you can do:

```sh
yarn global add file:/fullpath/to/myproject
```

Comment: It doesn't work. `bash: /Users/paulrberg/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/bin/create-eth-app: No such file or directory`

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, it works! Key is to do the absolute path, or `yarn global add "file:$(pwd)/sub/folder"`

Answer (score 1):

Yarn, unfortunately, does not seem to support this directly in any way. The best thing I've found is to symbolically link the file to the user's yarn bin folder.

On Windows: `%LOCALAPPDATA%/Yarn/bin`

On Linux: `~/.yarn/bin/`

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the command might look like? I've tried `ln -s ./script.sh ~/.yarn/bin/my-script` but doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to test within a node project, even if it's a global cli tool.

### Example

Say I want to test a global tool `my-yarn-cli`, which has a few commands `new`, `--help`, `--version`, etc...

1. In the cli tool directory, `yarn link` this makes the local version of `my-yarn-cli` available to yarn.
2. In an empty project use `yarn link my-yarn-cli`, this adds a reference to the local version of `my-yarn-cli`
3. Test out commands using yarn as a proxy, for example:

   - `yarn my-yarn-cli --help`
   - `yarn my-yarn-cli --version`
   - `yarn my-yarn-cli new TEST_ARGUMENT`

This has been a useful workflow for me, and is much better than messing with symlinks or copying directories.